# Jquery ui slider range - separate event for left and right draggers

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I use many jQuery ui sliders as range sliders on one page. About 60 range sladers at one time.

Slider must do:

1. When i drag left dragger - right dragger must moove to. Its need for
   fix range and moove it on max/min line
2. When i drag right dragger - left not moove, but change len of range used in #1 action

For store len of range i use attr in html:

```
div class="slider" range="10"
```

- When i moove left dragger - i add range attr for calculate right
  dragger position.
- When i moove right dragger - i change range attr.

In javascript i use change and slide event - but i dont know left or right dragger create event.

How create separate events for left and right draggers in range slider?

Comment: To get more answers, you better show your code, and tell us what part of it it's not working the way you wanted.

Comment: Slider generate "slide" action... But both draggers of slider generate that action... I dont know how create separate actions for left and right draggers in slider...